# Reading from a URL Connection Java

Tags: java, url, html-parsing, urlconnection, datainputstream

I'm trying to read html code from a URL Connection. In one case the html file I'm trying to read includes 5 line breaks before the actual doc type declaration. In this case the input reader throws an exception for EOF.

```
URL pageUrl = 
    new URL(
        "http://www.nytimes.com/2011/03/15/sports/basketball/15nbaround.html"
    );

URLConnection getConn = pageUrl.openConnection();
getConn.connect();
DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(getConn.getInputStream());
//some read method here
```

Has anyone ran into a problem like this?

```
URL pageUrl = new URL("http://www.nytimes.com/2011/03/15/sports/basketball/15nbaround.html");
URLConnection getConn = pageUrl.openConnection();
getConn.connect();
DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(getConn.getInputStream());
String urlData = "";
while ((urlData = dis.readUTF()) != null)
    System.out.println(urlData);
```

//exception thrown

> java.io.EOFException
>       at java.io.DataInputStream.readUnsignedShort(DataInputStream.java:323)
>       at java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(DataInputStream.java:572)
>       at java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(DataInputStream.java:547)

in the case of bufferedreader, it just responds null and doesn't continue

```
pageUrl = new URL("http://www.nytimes.com/2011/03/15/sports/basketball/15nbaround.html");
URLConnection getConn = pageUrl.openConnection();
getConn.connect();
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getConn.getInputStream()));
String urlData = "";
while(true)
     urlData = br.readLine();
     System.out.println(urlData);
```

outputs null

Comment: Line breaks are not EOF. Perhaps post your reading code and the exception it is throwing?

Comment: I agree with the above comment from Brian R., without the stack trace it's hard to tell what the problem is.   Also, I'm not sure why you would need to use a DataInputStream to read HTML.  That is for reading Java primitive types (binary) mostly.   If you want to read line-by-line, BufferedReader is a better (non-deprecated) choice.

Answer (score 1):

You're using `DataInputStream` to read data that wasn't encoded using `DataOutputStream`. Examine the documented behavior for your call to `DataInputStream#readUtf()`; [it first reads two bytes](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/DataInput.html#readUTF%28%29) to form a 16-bit integer, indicating the number of bytes that follow comprising the UTF-encoded string. The data you're reading from the HTTP server is not encoded in this format.

Instead, the HTTP server is sending headers encoded in ASCII, per [*RFC 2616*](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt) sections 6.1 and 2.2. You need to read the headers as text, and then determine how the message body (the "entity") is encoded.

Answer (score 1):

This works fine:

```
package url;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.net.URL;

/**
 * UrlReader
 * @author Michael
 * @since 3/20/11
 */
public class UrlReader
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        UrlReader urlReader = new UrlReader();

        for (String url : args)
        {
            try
            {
                String contents = urlReader.readContents(url);
                System.out.printf("url: %s contents: %s\n", url, contents);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }


    public String readContents(String address) throws IOException
    {
        StringBuilder contents = new StringBuilder(2048);
        BufferedReader br = null;

        try
        {
            URL url = new URL(address);
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
            String line = "";
            while (line != null)
            {
                line = br.readLine();
                contents.append(line);
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            close(br);
        }

        return contents.toString();
    }

    private static void close(Reader br)
    {
        try
        {
            if (br != null)
            {
                br.close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) 
        throws MalformedURLException, IOException 
    {
        URL pageUrl = new URL("http://www.google.com");
        URLConnection getConn = pageUrl.openConnection();
        getConn.connect();
        BufferedReader dis = new BufferedReader( 
                                 new InputStreamReader(
                                     getConn.getInputStream()));
        String myString;
        while ((myString = dis.readLine()) != null)
        {
            System.out.println(myString);
        }
    }
}
```

Works perfectly. The URL you are supplying, however, returns nothing.

Comment: The supplied URL yields a 301 response ("Moved Permanently").

Comment: Ok thanks everyone. I didn't notice the 301, but now I fixed it