# Android, i cant read any web page easily

Tags: java, android, httpconnection

I'm trying to connect any web page by the easiest way. I learnt that i have to use AsyncTask but i want before to see this job.

```
package com.example.duzbaglanti;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {



    String biyazi = "ggg";
    TextView tv;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        Button benimtus = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        benimtus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                tv.setText(biyazi);
            }
        });



        HttpURLConnection benimconnection = null;
        try {
            URL benimurl = new URL("anypage");
            benimconnection = (HttpURLConnection) benimurl.openConnection();
            int sonuckodu = benimconnection.getResponseCode();
            if(sonuckodu == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                InputStream benimin = new BufferedInputStream(benimconnection.getInputStream());
                biyazi = benimin.toString();

                ///////
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("baglantihatasi","hata oldu",e);
        }
        finally { benimconnection.disconnect(); }




    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

when i click the button my string changes to 'Java.io.BufferedInputStream@4177b2a8' not my web page's output. what is the wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the implementation of `BufferedInputStream#toString()`?

```
InputStream benimin = new BufferedInputStream(benimconnection.getInputStream());
biyazi = benimin.toString();
```

There isn't actually one. So the method call defers to [`Object#toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29) as that is the first available implemented parent class method. That's implemented as such

```
public String toString() {
    return getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());
}
```

In other words it has nothing to do with the content of the `InputStream`. You need to actually read the stream into, possibly, an array of bytes and then convert that into a `String`. [Here's one way.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5371943/reading-from-a-url-connection-java)

Comment: how can i use it after my code
InputStream benimin = new BufferedInputStream(benimconnection.getInputStream());

Comment: @user2778565 The link in my answer provides details on how to get the contents of an `InputStream` into a `String`. Please read it carefully.

Answer (score 0):

Check your manifest file, whether you have added internet permission to your manifest file, If not, add it. Then it works!