# How to get the HTML content of a webpage as a string

Tags: android, http, get, server

Im trying to get the HTML content of this webpage http://dbxserver.dbxprts.com:7778/pls/apex/training.d_respuesta?p_id_camion=1002 as a String and put it in a variable how can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following method

```
public String getJson(String url) throws ClientProtocolException,
            IOException {
        StringBuilder build = new StringBuilder();
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        InputStream content = entity.getContent();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                content));
        String con;
        while ((con = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            build.append(con);
        }
        return build.toString();
    }
```

**Note**

```
url = "http://dbxserver.dbxprts.com:7778/pls/apex/training.d_respuesta?p_id_camion=1002";
```

This method return the value as string //20.5325117 # -100.4038478

Answer (score 0):

URLConnection
read data to string...
[Reading from a URL Connection Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5371943/reading-from-a-url-connection-java)
Or you can do an Android specific approach using WebView and over-riding the URL loading (longer effort).